# Set maximum row of the table with page-break and show remaining data to next page

Tags: html, node.js, row, page-break

I want to set the maximum number of row in each table and continue the data to the next page in the html. For example, I have 44 records and I need to show only 10 records in first html page and another 10 in another html page and goes on and finally with the last 4 records in the last page. I just need to know the logic to be used in this with for loop.

I tried this to display the first 10 records but, how to display the other records

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a simple pager but with data on different independent pages
Here is a part of code ... you just need to change $pageno variable to current page .. or you can catch it with GET or extract from pagename.

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
$no_of_records_per_page = 10;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

$total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
$total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
$res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
    //here goes the data
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```